# insert data except the same one(duplicate) in php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, loops, codeigniter

i have table **item** that consists

| id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Table |
| 2 | Computer |
| 3 | Dress |

i want to add new **item_name** but when it show the duplicate value of item_name it won't save the changes.

i have tried the operation using php and this is the source code

```
    $item_save= $this->model->get_item($id);
    
            if (array_count_values((array)$item_save['item_name']) > 0) {
                $result['items']['result'] = false;
            } else {
                $this->model->save('item', $param);
                $result['items']['result'] = true;
            }
```

but it turns out error.

what is wrong with my code? and which part should i fix so i can save the item_name without duplication? thanks in advance. i'm a beginner using php

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all items in your table and compare with your new item with a foreach loop ?

```
$duplicate = false ;
foreach ($item_array as $key => $value) {
 if (strtoupper($value['item_name']) ===  strtoupper($your_new_item['item_name'] )
     $duplicate = true;
}
if ($duplicate != true) 
    $this->model->save('item', $param);
```